# How to refer NPM installed libraries from web pages and templates?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, pug

I have installed, say, jQuery:

```
npm install jquery
```

Now my site has

```
ROOT/node_modules/jquery/*
```

subdirectory.

What to do next? Just write

```
<script src="/node_modules/jquery/src/jquery.js"></script>
```

Or I can do something to take `jquery.js` out this path and/or encode reference in some portable way?

For example, suppose I am using Jade template. Shoud I write just

```
script(src="/node_modules/jquery/src/jquery.js")
```

Comment: The [package page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery) provides some hints. You can of course link, symlink or just copy the file, but I guess the idea is to incorporate it to your favourite build tool and eventually get some `/js/scripts.min.js?v123` you can call from `<script>`.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question shortly: yes, you can copy `jquery.js` and move it to whatever folder you want. Then, you would have to change the src attribute in the script element, like this:

```
<script src="/new/path/jquery.js"></script>
```

However, in production cases, you would most likely want to join all the js files, and then only load a few files, like the following:

```
<script src="/path/libs.js"></script>
```

where `libs.js` contains all of our dependencies in correct order.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer to your question is : yes, you use it with the relative path as you put

`<script src="/node_modules/jquery/src/jquery.js"></script>`

To elaborate on use of NPM, it helps in the following ways

- Keeps the dependencies outside your code. So in your git repository you can ignore them (saves space and network). Also change of a library is done at one place instead of everywhere.
- You can recreate the dependencies easily. In case where you have deleted the dependencies or when new repo is built, you can run npm install and all dependencies are updated.
- Automatic dependency management - Where one package depends on another and in case where they are updated, nom automatically manages all dependencies.

So, in summary you are saved from managing the external packages.

Now in our code, you could use them the following way

1. We could refer to each library by giving relative path. This is straightforward approach.
2. Howewver, if you want to give alias root path, you can do that in builders like gulp or web pack by having variables.
3. The best approach is to bundle them as one js file and also minify them and use the bundle.js. For example, in web pack, you could mention all such files as vendor.bundle.js in web pack configuration and run it once. This will create vendor.bundle.js. You can use this bundle instead of jQuery. The benefit is while nom manages the dependent modules at lower level, you can bundle them in to another js which will result in smaller single file that will be performance wise better.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using any build tool then you can have a scripts folder where you can copy the required libraries manually. That way your source itself is your build that you will eventually deploy. Or if you are working on a medium or big project, you can take a more common approach and use a build tool like webpack, gulp or browserify which can import all the dependencies automatically. Webpack is great for big projects can do a number of things for you:

- can import your dependencies into chunks of files
- assets management
- minifies your dependencies to reduce the size
- compiles compile-to-js and compile-to-css languages like typescript and sass
- offers a dev server with hot reloading
- supports dynamic loading to download parts of js only if required on runtime

and many others. It adds a good bit of complexity to your code though.

For small projects however I think it is better to go with manually adding libraries and keeping things simple

Answer (score 0):

Dear what ever dependencies you are taking inside node project must be in Node_Modules and you must Specify the Dependencies path from Node_Module/dependency_path it will be better in Development of Project and in Production.May this be helpful for you